# un able to put more fields on the view

Tags: swiftui

I am not able to add another field to this form for some reason.
the issue is that whenever I add another field i get an error somehwere else.

right now i am getting the error ::
Extra argument in call
on the line:

```
 Button(action: {
```

on the component::

```
Button(action: {
//                    handle_signup()
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                          .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
```

i made a small video showing the error::
https://youtu.be/4QL9Qeygb68

if i comment out any of these fields the error goes away::
TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Name", text: $name)
IntFieldWithLabel(label: "Age", value: $age)

```
            RangeFieldView(label: "Height in ft and iches",start: $height_feet, first_field_label: "Feet", end: $height_inches, second_field_label: "Inches" )
            
            ToggleFieldView(label: "Interested In", selectedOption: $interested_sex, options: InterestedSex.allCases)

            TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Bio", text: $bio)
            TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Hometown", text: $home_town)
            TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Industry", text: $industry)
            ToggleFieldView(label: "Has kids", selectedOption: $hasKids, options: HasKids.allCases)
            ToggleFieldView(label: "Gender", selectedOption: $gender, options: Gender.allCases)
```

which is super super weird.

If i add the button between the other fields, the most bottom field gets the error..

this is the whole component::

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ProfileEditView: View {
    @State private var email = "jcasasma22il@gmail.com"
    @State private var password = "jcasasmail"
    let mode: String

    @State private var state = "new"
    @State private var height_feet: Int = 5
    @State private var height_inches: Int = 10

    @State private var name = "juan"
    @State private var age: Int = 1
    @State private var bio = "i like big butts"
    @State private var industry = ""
    @State private var home_town = ""
    @State private var hasKids: HasKids = .no

    @State private var gender = Gender.male
    @State private var interested_sex = InterestedSex.female
    @State private var is_authenticated = false
    @State private var images: Image?
    @State private var is_image_picked_presented = false
    @State private var imageData: Data?

    @State private var latitude: Float?
    @State private var longitude: Float?
    @AppStorage("userData") var userData: Data?

    @EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManager
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var sheet_manager: SheetManager

    let user_service = UserService()
    let firebase_storage = FirebaseStorageService()
    let user_util = UserUtil()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    is_image_picked_presented.toggle()
                }) {
                    if let images = images {
                        images
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .sheet(isPresented: $is_image_picked_presented) {
                    ImagePicker(selectedImage: $images, imageData: $imageData)
                }

                .padding()

                TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Name", text: $name)
                IntFieldWithLabel(label: "Age", value: $age)

                RangeFieldView(label: "Height in ft and iches",start: $height_feet, first_field_label: "Feet", end: $height_inches, second_field_label: "Inches" )
                
                ToggleFieldView(label: "Interested In", selectedOption: $interested_sex, options: InterestedSex.allCases)

                TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Bio", text: $bio)
                TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Hometown", text: $home_town)
                TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Industry", text: $industry)
                ToggleFieldView(label: "Has kids", selectedOption: $hasKids, options: HasKids.allCases)
                ToggleFieldView(label: "Gender", selectedOption: $gender, options: Gender.allCases)

                Button(action: {
//                    handle_signup()
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }

                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $is_authenticated, content: {
                    BottomNavBarView()
                })
            }
            .onAppear {
                if mode == "edit" {
                    if let userData = userData,
                       let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userData) as? [String: Any] {

                        if let genderRawValue = json["gender"] as? String,
                           let gender = Gender(rawValue: genderRawValue) {
                            self.gender = gender
                        }
                        if let interested_sex_raw_value = json["interested_sex"] as? String,
                           let interested_sex = InterestedSex(rawValue: interested_sex_raw_value) {
                            self.interested_sex = interested_sex
                        }

                        if let email_raw_value = json["email"] as? String {
                            print("email_raw_value: ", email_raw_value)
                            self.email = email_raw_value
                        } else {
                            print("Email key not found in JSON.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Edit profile")
            .popup(with: sheet_manager)
        }
    }


    private func handle_signup() {
        if state == "new" {
            sign_up_with_email()
        }
    }

    private func sign_up_with_email() {
        user_util.create_user_with_email(
            email: email,
            password: password,
            name: name,
            bio: bio,
            gender: gender,
            interested_sex: interested_sex,
            imageData: imageData!,
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            heightFeet: height_feet,
            heightInches: height_inches
        ) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let token):
                is_authenticated = true
            case .failure(let error):
                print("[VIEW]User creation failed. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    enum AuthenticationError: Error {
        case userCreationFailed
    }
}

struct ProfileEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileEditView(mode: "edit").environmentObject(SheetManager())
    }
}
```

i dont think the issue is on the fields, but here are the components used::

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldWithLabel: View {
    var label: String
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(label)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.black)

            TextField("Enter \(label)", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct TextFieldWithLabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Name", text: .constant("John Doe"))
    }
}
```

int::

```
import SwiftUI

struct IntFieldWithLabel: View {
    var label: String
    @Binding var value: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(label)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.black)

            TextField("Enter \(label)", value: $value, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct IntFieldWithLabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IntFieldWithLabel(label: "Age", value: .constant(25))
    }
}
```

range::

```
import SwiftUI

struct RangeFieldView: View {
    var label: String

    @Binding var start: Int
    var first_field_label: String
    
    @Binding var end: Int
    var second_field_label: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(label)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.bottom, 8)

            HStack {
                TextField(first_field_label, value: $start, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                Text("-")

                TextField(second_field_label, value: $end, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

toggle::

```
import SwiftUI
//
struct ToggleFieldView<T: Hashable>: View {
    var label: String
    @Binding var selectedOption: T
    var options: [T]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(label)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.bottom, 8)
            Picker("", selection: $selectedOption) {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                    Text(String(describing: option)).tag(option)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Adjust the frame width
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleFieldView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ToggleFieldView(label: "Gender", selectedOption: .constant(Gender.male), options: Gender.allCases)
    }
}
```

i tried asking chatgpt a bunch of ways but it didnt work

Comment: IF if add the button above the other fields, the most bottom field gets the error, its super weird

Answer (score 1):

View builders (including a view's `body`) can have a maximum of 10 direct child views. You have specified 11, so the final one in the list is where the error shows up.

You can avoid this hard limit by grouping some of the form elements together. You can use `Group` for this, e.g.:

```
Group {
  TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Name", text: $name)
  IntFieldWithLabel(label: "Age", value: $age)
  RangeFieldView(label: "Height in ft and iches",start: $height_feet, first_field_label: "Feet", end: $height_inches, second_field_label: "Inches" )
}

Group {
  ToggleFieldView(label: "Interested In", selectedOption: $interested_sex, options: InterestedSex.allCases)
  TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Bio", text: $bio)
  TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Hometown", text: $home_town)
  TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Industry", text: $industry)
  ToggleFieldView(label: "Has kids", selectedOption: $hasKids, options: HasKids.allCases)
  ToggleFieldView(label: "Gender", selectedOption: $gender, options: Gender.allCases)
}
```

`Group` has no implications on the visual layout so that should suffice for your existing code.

Another option is to use a `Form` for your controls, and break up the controls into visually distinct groups so that users can feel a little less overwhelmed by a long list. You can use `Section` - which is a group that has a visual impact, along with optional headers and footers – in that case. For example:

```swift
Form {
  TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Name", text: $name)

  Section("Personal info") {
    IntFieldWithLabel(label: "Age", value: $age)
    RangeFieldView(label: "Height in ft and iches",start: $height_feet, first_field_label: "Feet", end: $height_inches, second_field_label: "Inches" )
    ToggleFieldView(label: "Gender", selectedOption: $gender, options: Gender.allCases)
    ToggleFieldView(label: "Interested In", selectedOption: $interested_sex, options: InterestedSex.allCases)
  }

  Group("More details") {
    TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Bio", text: $bio)
    TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Hometown", text: $home_town)
    TextFieldWithLabel(label: "Industry", text: $industry)
    ToggleFieldView(label: "Has kids", selectedOption: $hasKids, options: HasKids.allCases)
  }
}
```

Comment: This limit of 10 childs is a pain in the ass. And the error from Xcode is never clear about what's going on.